# elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', '[1:16135] [bool] failed to parse field [filter]')

Tags: elasticsearch

This is the query i am using to fetch results based on cosine similarity and two different filters. I am trying to fetch es data based in cosine similarity with a few filters. I don’t know what i am doing wrong here.

````
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": [
          {
            "term": {
              "bot_id": "embedding_test"
            }
          },
          {
            "terms": {
              "file_uuid": ["embedding_test"]
            }
          },
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "nba",
              "query": {
                "script_score": {
                  "script": {
                    "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['nba.embedding'].value) + 1.0",
                    "params": {
                      "query_vector": [1.0, 0.5, 0.2]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "size": 100,
    "min_score": 1.0
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The `script_score` query [**requires** you to specify a `query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-score-query.html#script-score-top-level-params)  alongside the script in order to restrict the document set on which the script is running. You can specify `match_all` if you want to run the script on all documents (i.e. brute force vector search)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "bot_id": "embedding_test"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "file_uuid": [
              "embedding_test"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "nba",
            "query": {
              "script_score": {
                "query": {              <--------
                  "match_all": {}       <-------- ADD THIS
                },                      <--------
                "script": {
                  "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'nba.embedding') + 1.0",
                  "params": {
                    "query_vector": [
                      1,
                      0.5,
                      0.2
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 100,
  "min_score": 1
}
```

Also, second note, you should replace `doc['nba.embedding'].value` by simply the field name, i.e. `nba.embedding`, in your script.