# elasticsearch script_score query with java client

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using spring-boot 3.1.5 and spring-data-elasticsearch 5.1.5 java project.
I try to make client program with this query.

```
GET vector_search/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "Math.max(0,cosineSimilarity(params.queryVector,'text_VEC'))",
              "params": {
                "queryVector": [0.1,0.1,0.0.1~~~~~~]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and my java code is like this.

```
        Query searchQuery = NativeQuery.builder()
                .withQuery(q -> q.scriptScore(m -> m.script(fn -> fn.inline(InlineScript.of(fn2 -> fn2.source("Math.max(0,cosineSimilarity(params.queryVector,'text_VEC'))"))))))
                .withQuery(q -> q.scriptScore(m -> m.script(fn -> fn.inline(InlineScript.of(fn2 -> fn2.params(params))))))
                .withMaxResults(5)
                .build();
```

but i got this exception.
co.elastic.clients.util.MissingRequiredPropertyException: Missing required property 'ScriptScoreQuery.query'
at co.elastic.clients.util.ApiTypeHelper.requireNonNull(ApiTypeHelper.java:76)
at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.ScriptScoreQuery.(ScriptScoreQuery.java:63)
at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.ScriptScoreQuery.(ScriptScoreQuery.java:49)
at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.ScriptScoreQuery$Builder.build(ScriptScoreQuery.java:184)
at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.ScriptScoreQuery$Builder.build(ScriptScoreQuery.java:124)
at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.Query$Builder.scriptScore(Query.java:1601)

what did i miss?

c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states it

> Missing required property 'ScriptScoreQuery.query' at

The `script_score` query requires you to [specify a `query`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77185946/4604579)

```
GET vector_search/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "query": {       <---
                ...          <--- this is required
            },               <---
            "script": {
              "source": "Math.max(0,cosineSimilarity(params.queryVector,'text_VEC'))",
              "params": {
                "queryVector": [0.1,0.1,0.0.1~~~~~~]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So you also need to specify a query in

```
    Query searchQuery = NativeQuery.builder()
            .withQuery(q -> q.scriptScore(
                 m -> m.query(...)      <---- this is required
                       .script(fn -> fn.inline(InlineScript.of(
                           fn2 -> fn2.source("Math.max(0, cosineSimilarity(params.queryVector, 'text_VEC'))")                                              
                                     .params(params)
                       )
                     )
                  )
               )
            )
            .withMaxResults(5)
            .build();
```

Comment: Understand! It's works now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked out!

Comment: Another question, 
is there any way to use multiple script_socre with using weight, boost_mode?

Comment: Sorry Didn't know that. I accepted  